# How do you install Aeon skin on XBMC 10+ for Windows?

Tags: kodi, skin

How do you install Aeon skin on XBMC 10+ for Windows ?

It's not in the skin install dialog and when I download the Aeon package, I copy it to the Skins folder and from what I've read this should be enough, but even after restarting XBMC, it doesn't show up.

Comment: Actually, it's the same principle to install any skin. This is just a mod to the original (unmaintained) skin. A better mod, in my opinion.

I'm the site author. Any doubts, fire away and ask.

h.udo

Comment: I can't remember what it was called, but I think there's a tool somewhere on the internet that allows you to browse through skins and automatically download & install them for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a slightly different skin, you should check it out, but here is how to install it

http://xbmcmediacenter.com/xbmc-aeon-mq2-skin-new-improved/

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any tool to install skins or anything else in XBMC. Just use the built in add-on manager.

Got to System >> Add-ons

Install from there. Install skins, video plugins, media scrapers and hundreds more applications.

Check my link to find out more.